# Holo Lens 2 emulator virtual keyboard not displaying in edge browser

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I have seen in the Microsoft Documentation in the following link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/devices/designing-for-mr#the-2d-app-input-overview

That a virtual keyboard can be launched inside the Edge Browser. However, when I open the Holo Lens 2 Emulator no virtual keyboard is coming up.

**How can I make the virtual keyboard available inside the Edge Browser?**

**And is there any way to display the non-native keyboard in the MRTKToolKit as the virtual keyboard to be display inside the edge browser?**

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make the virtual keyboard available inside the Edge Browser?

Actually, if you test it with the HoloLens device, click the search bar and the Edge will launch the system keyboard for you. But in the Hololens2 simulator, please press F4 to uncheck "Use keyboard for simulation", and then your PC's keyboard input will be sent through to the HoloLens.

> And is there any way to display the non-native keyboard in the MRTKToolKit as the virtual keyboard to be display inside the edge browser?

For two separate processes, MRTK cannot invoke the system keyboard for another process. If you want to invoke the system keyboard in your own project, call Unity API [`TouchScreenKeyboard.Open()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard.Open.html), more information please see: [System keyboard](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_SystemKeyboard.html)

Comment: In the Hololens2 simulator when I select use keyboard for simulation instead, the virtual keyboard is not appearing on the screen after launching Edge Browser.

Comment: For the second question, when I try running the demo with the system keyboard example I get the following error: "Keyboard not supported on this platform." Can I use the non-native keyboard under the Experimental feature instead of the system keyboard for Edge Browser? I used the following link https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/6492

Comment: For the question that invoking keyboard in the simulator, in my experience you can multiple click F4 to invoke the system keyboard in the simulator. For the error "Keyboard not supported on this platform", if you play the scene on the Unity Editor The system keyboard will not show up. Besides, the non-system keyboard from MRTK not supported to be invoked for the edge through a Unity APP.

Comment: F4 is the shortcut key for either toggling whether or not the desktop keyboard is used to move around and interact with the virtual environment or if the desktop keyboard input is sent directly to the focused app running in the emulator.  You should not turn off "Use keyboard for simulation" unless you want to use your hardware keyboard to type into an app in the emulator.  Turning this option off *and* typing will dismiss the on-screen keyboard if it is open.  Simply toggling this option has no effect on whether or not the on-screen keyboard appears or disappears.

Comment: Changing the xdesku.xml file worked for me and now I am able to see the OS Keyboard inside the Edge Browser.

Answer (score 0):

For current versions of the HoloLens 2 Emulator, please edit the file xdesku.xml.  You will find this in Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft XDE\10.0.18362.0\skus\hde.  You will need administrator permissions to modify the file.  In the file, search for "EnableMobileKeyboardEmulation".  On the line that contains this name, change 'Data="1"' to 'Data="0"' and save your change.  When you launch the emulator from that point on, the on-screen keyboard will appear when appropriate.  This will be fixed in a future update to the emulator.  Please do not turn off "Use keyboard for simulation" unless you truly want to use your desktop keyboard to type directly into the emulator.  Typing with your desktop keyboard will dismiss the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Thank you! This worked and now I can see the OS Keyboard inside the Edge Browser.

Comment: Do you know how can I control the Edge Browser and the OS keyboard with the eyes instead of hand tracking?

Comment: The system-provided on-screen keyboard is designed for hand interaction.  There is no option to control it with the eyes.